# R grouping function to select last value in the row

Tags: r, grouping

Give a data set like this

```
    date        X
    2012-10-02  2210
    2012-10-02  2215
    2012-10-03  410
    2012-10-03  430
    2012-10-03  535
    2012-10-03  550
    2012-10-04  555
    2012-10-04  600
    2012-10-04  605
    2012-10-04  610
```

How do I aggregate/Group on date and select only the last value on X  in R language.

```
    date        X
    2012-10-02  2215
    2012-10-03  550
    2012-10-04  610
```

If I need to sum X by date, then I can use aggregate function

```
   aggregate(x, by=list(x=date), FUN=sum)
```

But my requirement is to select only the last row from each group. How to do this. Please advise.

Comment: Look at the documentation of the `aggregate` function.

Comment: @Roland Yeah I tried aggregate function first , but I don't know how will select last X for every unique date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(X=X[.N]) , date]
#        date    X
#1: 2012-10-02 2215
#2: 2012-10-03  550
#3: 2012-10-04  610
```

Or using `base R`

```
 aggregate(X~date, df1,FUN=tail,1)
 #        date    X
 #1 2012-10-02 2215
 #2 2012-10-03  550
 #3 2012-10-04  610
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  slice(n()) # selects only the last row (nth row of n total) within each subgroup
```

Produces:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: date

        date    X
1 2012-10-02 2215
2 2012-10-03  550
3 2012-10-04  610
```